# Can I integrate a for loop into a if statement that checks if a number exists in an array?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, linear-search

I’m writing a simple code that performs a linear search on the array numbers to see if a number entered by a user exists in it, but I keep getting syntax errors.

```
numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
num= Input("enter number")
If num[for count in range(0,len(numbers))] ==numbers[for count in range(0,len(numbers))]:
    print("num is found")
else:
    print("num not found")
```

Have i written the IF statement correctly, or have I made a mistake

Comment: `if int(num) in numbers:` and you have to fix the capitalizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
num= input("enter number")
if int(num) in numbers:
    print("num is found")
else:
    print("num not found")
```

Also if you want to make it so that it accounts for non-number responses you could use:

```
numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
num= input("enter number")
try:
    if int(num) in numbers:
        print("num is found")
    else:
        print("num not found")
except:
    print("Sorry, you can only enter integers.")
```

Comment: Oh I didnt know you could do that, thanks. But what I wanted to know was if me integrating the for loop into the if statement was correct, and how to correct it if not

Comment: @stinkeman yes that is incorrect, you cannot put for loops within an if statement unless you are using list comprehension

Comment: @stinkeman if you want to use a for loop you can do:
for number in numbers:
    if number == num:
        print('num found')

but this will print each time the number is found in the list.

Comment: Oh but I can write a for loop that iterates from 1 to len(numbers) and write an if statement to check if num[count] == num[count] right? Also thanks for your help

Comment: partially, you can write your for loop like that but you cannot index num at count.

num[count] will give an error because int is not indexable.

but you can do num == numbers[count] inside that same loop and it will work.

Comment: If you want a `for` loop you could use any: `if any(number = int(num) for number in numbers):`. But for checking if something is **in** a list you really should use `in`.

Comment: well said, matt.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know the in function existed, that makes it a lot easier for me, thanks